# Matrices in an equation

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

It must be an easy one, but I do not figure out how to solve it.

$$Z^2\cdot\begin{pmatrix}3 & 0 \\ 0 & 3\end{pmatrix}\cdot Z^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 3 \\ 1 & 2\end{pmatrix}$$

being $Z$ a matrix.

EDIT: Ok, I have it know haha! Thank you guys. Now it's the time I tell you I study Electrical Engineering and all of you can laugh at me because I didn't know how to solve a high school problem (YAI!)

Comment: try using the fact that matrix multiplication is associative

Comment: What do you know about the identity matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Bring a scalar out from one of the matrices.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Take out the scalar $3$ and 
use the fact that $Z*Z^{-1}= I$